# Using obj file format causes code to infinitely load

Tags: loading, p5.js, infinite

I am trying to code for a little project of my own and I have seemed to come across an issue of which I simply cannot figure out.

I am using p5.js and I am simply trying to load a .obj model into my code and trying to preview it but it is stuck on 'loading...' for an infinite amount of time.

any help is appreciated - below is the code.

```
let chicken;

function preload() {
  chicken = loadModel('assets/chicken.obj');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(100, 100, WEBGL);
}

function draw() {
  background(200);
  rotateX(frameCount * 0.01);
  rotateY(frameCount * 0.01);
  model(chicken);
}
```

Comment: Because your code is exactly the same as the docs here https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadModel it might be worth replicating it in p5js editor https://editor.p5js.org/ so we can see it running

Comment: tried and does not work :(

Comment: Send us a link to the editor

Comment: https://editor.p5js.org/taccodomestic/sketches/op_du-aVO

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue with the object you're trying to pass it. P5.js lib has a function called `parseObj(model, lines);`

it is failing at:
          `model.vertices.push(loadedVerts.v[vertParts[0]].copy());`

Giving the error: `p5.js:92586 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'copy' of undefined`

Which to me suggests there's something wrong with the 3D model you're trying to create.